# Jquery Fade in for a div within a div

Tags: jquery, html, web

Please help me on this.

This is my webpage.

```
<div id="wrapper">

   <div id="header">
      header text
   </div>

   <div id="content">
      content text
   </div>

</div>
```

I want to fade-in the #content block.

When I use  `$("#wrapper").fadeIn(1500);` it works fine and it fades in the whole page But when i use  `$("#content").fadeIn(1500);` it never works, nothing happends in regards to fading.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried  `$("#wrapper #content").fadeIn(1500);` too, but no luck, can you guys please tell me how to target the #content div only?

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing a sample page / code, but it sounds like you've got the `#wrapper` hidden but not the `#content`.

So it works when you fade-in `#wrapper` (thus showing all contained content) but it doesn't work when you fade-in `#content` because it's parent (`#wrapper`) is still hidden.

You might want to look at changing the `#wrapper` to be visible by default and the `#content` to hidden, so that a fade-in will show it correctly.

Again, this is all just conjecture at this point. If you add a link / sample then we can perhaps give a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me. See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xwqPA/

Comment: Thanks. I updated it the way i want. This is what I was after. Thanks heaps guys. http://jsfiddle.net/xwqPA/1/

Comment: Hi Conner, just found out this doesnt work on ie8. what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Set content div to `display: none` by default:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    header text
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="display: none;">
    content text
  </div>
</div>​​​
```

Comment: @user1074803 you are welcome. I don't know why someone down-voted me on this one. Maybe a too short answer.

Comment: thanks @ahren I will try to "ctrl + K" next time I want to highlight some code within a sentence :-)

Comment: No worries @HighKickX, you can also use the ` character - which (on a US-layout keyboard) is just below the esc key.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting two jQuery elements, separate them with commas:

$("#wrapper, #content").fadeIn(1500);

See [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

EDIT: Since this was down-voted, I feel the need to clarify further... You say that fading in #wrapper by itself works. From that, I can assume that #wrapper is hidden by default. Therefore, if you intend to "show" any of #wrapper's child elements, you will need to fade it in (or at least set it's display property to 'block' using `show()`) before you can attempt to fade in #content. This can be done by performing the fade on BOTH the wrapper and content divs as show above.